# Compile a i386 library on ARM-Cortex Ubuntu distro

Tags: ubuntu, embedded, arm, libaria

I developed a C++ application to control my mobile robot on my i386 pc by using Ubuntu 11.04.

Now, i have to run this C++ application on a development board named [Pandaboard](http://pandaboard.org/content/ubuntu-pandaboard) which is based on ARM Cortex omap4 processor.

On this board, i've installed [Ubuntu 11.10](http://www.omappedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Pre-Built_Binaries) with pre-build binaries.

The problem is that in order to compile my C++ application i have to install [libaria](http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/ARIA) which is ARIA open source library which i use to control my motors; when i try to install this library with g++-4.6 i receive errors like this:

> Unable to recognise the format of the input file
>   `/usr/local/Aria/lib/libArNetworking.so'

I think this is because this library is for i386 but i'm on ARM architecture.

Is there any possibility to be able to compile this library on my board?
(i can change operating system, if it is needed; what's important for me it's to be able to run my C++ application on my board and not on my pc)

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**: **I installed binutils-multiarch and then it compiled fine**.

I tried to compile the examples and the procedure was ok, but if i try to run one of them, i get this error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libAria.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

the library exists in /usr/local/Aria/lib and i added it to **/etc/ld.so.config** in this way:

> include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf include /usr/local/Aria/lib

and then i run "**sudo ldconfig**"

but this didn't solve the problem. :(

If i type: locale libAria.so, it returns me no path.

Can you help me with this last problem?

On my other pc, i didn't had this issue.

Comment: The source code is distributed under the GPL.  Have you tried downloading and compiling it?

Comment: yes, with make and sudo make install.. but it didn't solved the problem

Comment: I edited the topic because now it seems to compile but i have another problem

Comment: Please write an answer that documents the solution you found and then accept it.  That way, other people who have the same problem can benefit from your pain :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved by using binutils-multiarch and then i compiled again the library by specifing my g++ current version and by adding the lib patch to ld.so.config text file before to build the examples.